# How do I express 'pen to paper' in relation to a computer?

Tags: idioms

I wrote an email to someone this morning and said that I had not yet 'put pen to paper' and then I attempted to express that in modern terms.

But I stumbled to express 'paper', uncertain what 'substance' I am producing when I  take up the 'pen' of my keyboard.

What, exactly, would be the modern idiom, using computing over the internet, to express 'putting pen to paper' ?

Comment: I usually say “getting it down in black and white”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found lots of posts using "fingers to keyboard." Here are a few examples:

> Putting pen to paper (or fingers to keyboard) ([source](https://saa.audiology.org/educational-opportunities/undergraduate-students/undergraduate-resources/personal-statement-supplement/putting-pen-to-paper-or-fingers-to-keyboard))
>
> Motivation to put pen to paper - or fingers to keyboard. ([source](http://www.seankeefer.com/motivation-to-put-pen-to-paper-or-fingers-to-keyboard/))
>
> Writing tips for anyone who puts pen to paper or fingers to keyboard. ([source](https://www.parenttoday.org/writing-tips-for-anyone-who-puts-pen-to-paper-or-fingers-to-keyboard/))

This new old idiom sounds quite modern now, doesn't it?

Comment: But the keyboard does not equate to 'paper'. What I write is not _recorded_ on the keyboard.

Comment: @NigelJ What is the modern equivalent to 'chomping at the bit' going from horses to automobiles? Sometimes there's no one-to-one correspondence that fits all the nuances. 'Fingers to keyboard' is what captures the intention of "I'm not just thinking of things, I'm starting to really write".

Comment: @Mitch 'Revving the engine' is the modern equivalent, I suppose. Raring to go. I suppose 'fingers' and 'keyboard' are all we have, substantial : the rest is just electrons, I guess.